# what is J9VMInternals, how does it work?

Tags: java, debugging, nullpointerexception, classloader

In java

```
class C{
   public void d(){
          ...
       E.f();
          ...
   }
}
```

the stack trace would be

```
at a.b.C.d(C.java:300)
at a.b.E.f(E.java:500)
```

but if i see something like this, what do i make of 'J9VMInternals' class

```
at a.b.E.f(E.java:500)
     ...
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
at a.b.c.d(c.java:300)
```

Original stack trace i am trying to debug

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.initializeClassLoaderAssertStatus(ClassLoader.java:1215)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.<init>(ClassLoader.java:167)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.<init>(ClassLoader.java:126)
                   ....
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initializeImpl(Native Method)
    at java.lang.J9VMInternals.initialize(J9VMInternals.java:200)
    at <J2EE_listner_contextInitializedMethod>
```

I am on java 1.6.0_24 weblogic 11

Answer (score -5):

Do you expect your class to be instantiated out of thin air? The JVM loads it and initializes it and you will see such stack traces along with your classes

Comment: as far as i can understand, classloader loads the class, what does J9VMInternals do?

Comment: I think it is an `IBM`s specific class that is inside the JVM code and manages the rest of the calls (classloaders etc).

Comment: But you say `WebLogic` which is IBM

Comment: websphere is ibm, weblogic is bea bought by oracle. i am using sun provided jre instead of one shipped with weblogic(jrocket)

Comment: I have seen such exception trace (i.e. with `JVM9Internals`) only in IBM JRE.Don't remember ever seeing it with Oracle

Comment: Check which java you are actually deploying

Comment: I think you are using IBM. This seems to be the `J9VMInternals` http://www.koders.com/java/fid27C75B4F959D8379A73214652FABC33F7C2E646E.aspx?s=z.4 and seems to call `native` methods e.g. to do `init` of the constructor.I am don't know at which point this is called

Comment: Here is the out put from my machine for version check
**$ java -version**
----------------------
java version "1.6.0_24"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_24-b50)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.1-b02, mixed mode)
----------------------

Comment: But how do you know that this is the java actually used by `WebLogic`?Did you check if there are other jre's in your machine?

Comment: yes, "ps -ef|grep weblogic" gives me right java i need to look for